# Windows 10 does not detect usb device after some time

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers

I have windows Version 10.0.14393 Build 14393.

The issue that I am facing is that the usb ports are unable to detect devices after some time. By devices I mean pendrives as well.

I have to reboot the pc and then It works normally. No matter how much time is passed the usb port works after reboot. But does not work on initial load.

Under the device **manager>usb hub>properties the option "Allow the computer to turn off the device "** is unchecked.

-Thanks

Comment: That's how Windows 10 is. Buggy and not ready for prime time. There is no solution to this problem, and unless a miracle happens, I am afraid you are condemned to suffer this problem for the rest of your life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved now by repairing windows 10 as mentioned in this windows community answer [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/how-to-perform-a-repair-upgrade-using-the-windows/35160fbe-9352-4e70-9887-f40096ec3085)